# Intellisense and code suggestion not working in Visual Studio 2013 after adding C++ projects

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio-2013, intellisense

Good day!
I add some solution(with c++ projects) to my .Net solution.

After that - i show message box from VS that Intellisense will use another database for C++ projects... so, i press OK and...
And Intellisence does not work.

For example, i type:

```
public void Test()
{
   File.. //i can not add namespace for this class.
   // i should type:
  System.IO.File (at that way Intellisence works)       
 }
```

So, can you help me to make Intellisence works.
Thank you!

P.S. i go to Options->Text Editor->C#->General and make 'Auto list members','Hide advanced members','Parameter information' on.

Answer (score 0):

Hm... it seems that TFS disconnected and i create new .cs file outside of project.
When i include this file to project and to TFS- it works.